# Is this a good way to store XML data in SQL SERVER 2008?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm doing a feasibility study for storing data in the following structure with SQL SERVER 2008:

-MYTABLE
|ID|RECORDS|BRANCH_OFFICE|MONTH|YEAR

The RECORDS column has the XML data type and it will look like:

```
<visits>
  <visit id="000112233">
    <costumer>Mr. One Costumer</costumer>
    <date>2011-02-10</date>
    <employee>MAT01234</employee>
  </visit>
  <visit id="000112234">
    <costumer>Mr. Another Costumer</costumer>
    <date>2011-02-12</date>
    <employee>MAT01235</employee>
  </visit>
  <visit id="000112235">
    <costumer>Mr. Some Costumer</costumer>
    <date>2011-02-12</date>
    <employee>MAT01234</employee>
  </visit>
  <visit id="000112236">
    <costumer>Mr. Some Costumer</costumer>
    <date>2011-02-15</date>
    <employee>MAT01235</employee>
  </visit>
</visits>
```

I'm intending to query the xml column with xquery, is this a good way to store these data?
If i want to get the list of visits occurring in 2011-10, adding a tag with the difference of days between the "date" tag and now, how could it be?

Comment: Use XML if your data spec is variable or loosely defined. That's the primary benefit of using XML in SQL Server. If it's a fixed schema, however, you are better off taking Mark's suggestion below and mapping your XML schema to tables.

Comment: also posted [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836848/is-this-a-good-way-to-store-xml-data-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @Julio can you post your SO comment here as well please?

Answer (score 3):

> ...is this a good way to store these data?

No, this is probably the worst way to store this data if you want to query it effectively. You need to study some [database normalisation examples](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878) before you go any further with this

This is a very quick sketch up of a possible schema that could be used. Incomplete and untested but it should be clear how this maps to your XML fragment.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer
(
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL
    , Title VARCHAR(20)
    , FirstName VARCHAR(100)
    , LastName VARCHAR(100)
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Customer
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Customer PRIMARY KEY (CustomerId ASC)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee
(
    EmployeeNumber VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , Title VARCHAR(20)
    , FirstName VARCHAR(100)
    , LastName VARCHAR(100)
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Employee PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeNumber ASC)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Visit
(
    VisitId INT NOT NULL
    , VisitDate DATETIME
    , CustomerId INT
    , EmployeeNumber VARCHAR(10)
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Visit
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Visit PRIMARY KEY (VisitId ASC)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Visit WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Visit_Customer] FOREIGN KEY(CustomerId)
REFERENCES dbo.Customer (CustomerId)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Visit WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Visit_Employee] FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeNumber)
REFERENCES dbo.Employee (EmployeeNumber)
```